# Kinect microphone array order

Tags: matlab

I have started using kinect microphones.
I can get wav file using Matlab code:

```
fname='out.wav';
f=fopen(fname,'r+');
fseek(f,20,0);
fwrite(f,[3 0]);
fclose(f);
y=wavread(fname);
wavwrite(y(:,1),16000,'out_hello_1.wav');
wavwrite(y(:,2),16000,'out_hello_2.wav');
wavwrite(y(:,3),16000,'out_hello_3.wav');
wavwrite(y(:,4),16000,'out_hello_4.wav');

[wave,fs]=wavread('out_hello_1.wav'); % read file into memory 
[wave2,fs2]=wavread('out_hello_2.wav');
[wave3,fs3]=wavread('out_hello_3.wav');
[wave4,fs4]=wavread('out_hello_4.wav');
```

And my problem is here I recorded `out.wav` and produced `out_hello_1.wav` and `2`, `3`, `4` etc.

BUT how can I know which wav(`out_hello_1`) file is recorded from which one(microphone)?

if order is `"out_hello_1, out_hello_2,...."` in this code, what is the order of microphone of the kinect in the real device?

I cannot upload picture then tell me like from right side mic is 1,2,3,4 or left side

so blinking led of kinect exists on the right side...

Answer (score 0):

If your are taking raw audio (sounds like it) this is relatively easy. Blow directly on each mic port or run the port (opening for each mic) individually and state the mic number. In your recording, the mic you have blown or rubbed on will have a significantly larger signal level. Rubbing and Blowing act as close proximity audio source picked up by the microphone towards which the action is directed and the other mics should pick up very little of it.

If on the other hand you are receiving processed audio (doesn't sound like it, as it would probably be a mono or stereo stream and not 4 channels), then you will get replicated audio across all streams.